# How to scroll from the middle of the image in the scrollview?

Tags: iphone

Hi I am new to iphone.

What I did is creating a horizontal scroll view. In the view I am displaying 20 images.

In the scroll view images start from 1 st image. But I need image start from 10 and then it is easy to scroll left and right.

How can I done this?

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad`, set the scroll view's `contentOffset` so that it's set at position of the 10th image.